# Implement Open Graph Protocol in my web application

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am interested to implement Facebook way of link sharing feature in my web application. In FB when we paste a link it shows the content of link as thumbnail,few text etc.

- How can I do that?
- I know its Open Graph Protocol but how to implement it in my web application(based on spring MVC)?
- What are the technology needed for this? I am a java,jquery guy.
- Is it necessary to use facebook for this?

Comment: Do you want to read the contents of a facebook feed in your app, or do you want to share a link inside your app so it appears on facebook?

Comment: I want that if a user paste any link in my web application it should show the link content on html page same as FB does. I dont want any FB support.I want to implement my own methods.

Answer (score 1):

Open Graph isn't a library or a script you can use to build an application that is capable of doing what you want. Open Graph is a Protocol that follows a set of rules that provide a convinient scheme of building  social applications.

By doing so, it's made sure that there is a standarized way to work with that data.

So the short answer: OG does not provide such a functionality, you have to build it by yourself (though there are pretty good links and scripts that make your life much easier: http://ogp.me/ scroll to the very bottom). Instead by using OG, you make sure that every application that works with OG (facebook and google to name a few examples) can work with your data properly.

It might not be the answer you searched for, but I think it should give you a little information on what OG really is.